# Why would one ever use lambda beyond the declaring scope or functions called from the declaring scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

There are several ways to pass callable objects as parameters or to store them for future use. You can create a class with `operator()`, you can define a function and pass a pointer to it, and, since C++11, you can define a lambda via `[](){}` syntax.

I appreciate lambda syntax as a shortcut in expressions such as `find_if` that often beg for a compact callable expression. What I don't understand about lambda is the desire to use them outside the point of their declaration and risk introducing dangling references and such. C++ already has a powerful way to pass callable objects around which is much safer then lambda, and in those situation there is no benefit of compact expression of lambda.

Thus the question: why does C++11 allow use of a lambda outside the function that declares is or the functions called from it (and therefore introduces the risk of dangling references, etc)? Could you give an example where keeping lambda live outside the declaring function would be desirable?

Comment: If lambdas weren't copyable, you wouldn't be able to use them with `find_if`

Comment: There are two sides of the story - first is why C++ allows them to be copyable - and this is simply so that they can be passed to algorithms, which accept their arguments by value. The other question is why some people abuse this and really make long-living copies of lambdas. That I do not know.

Comment: @SergeyA storing a long-living copy of a lambda for a call back seems fine to me. Do you consider that abuse of lambdas?

Comment: @Praetorian: changed the title to clarify.

Comment: @user2079303: I do. Many of the problems associated with lambdas, such as dangling references to the variables in the scope where the lambdas were declared, come from the ability to store the lambda beyond the declaring scope.

Comment: @Michael what do you consider a safe alternative? You mention a *powerful wat to pass callable objects around*. What are you referring to?

Comment: Could I not wish to have a function generating and returning my lambda (e.g. an equation parser)

Comment: @user2079303, by long-living I mean outliving it's initial scope. I firmly believe it is abusal.

Comment: Your original question was *why would anyone do X?*. Now it's *why would anyone do X, except in case A or B?*. Soon you'll need to add another case once someone points out a useful one Short answer is that there are legitimate use cases where you may want to lambda to outlive its original scope, and restricting it would get annoying; this is not something you want from a feature supposed to be a convenience. Can you shoot yourself in the foot creating dangling references? Sure, but you can do that with just about anything in C++ by using it the wrong way.

Comment: The only alternative is to create an adhoc function object, which is far less convenient to use and pollutes the namespace. And as praetorian already said, if you want lambdas to be usable with algorithms, there is just no way to prevent it's use outside of its point of declaration. If you are looking for a language that makes it hard to shoot yourself in the foot C++ isn't the one.

Comment: @user2079303: I refer to `struct { operator() };` which is extremely flexible.

Comment: @Michael which is the same as a lambda, except with different declaration syntax. How is it safer?

Comment: @user2079303: it's safer because it doesn't encourage you to capture local variables.

Comment: @Michael how does the lambda encourage the capture of local variables?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function which is registered to be called when a future event occurs.  It would be convenient to define it as a lambda, but it has to live beyond the scope in which it is defined:

for example

```
m_button->setOnClick(YOUR LAMBDA GOES HERE);
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand about lambda is the desire to use them outside the point of their declaration and risk introducing dangling references and such. C++ already has a powerful way to pass callable objects around which is much safer then lambda, and in those situation there is no benefit of compact expression of lambda.

(1) Lambda isn't implicitly less safe than any other way of defining function objects. The way of passing a lambda is exactly the same as passing an instance of a named functor.

You can store references in a named functor, and you can capture references in a lambda. Storing a reference to a local object in either of those cases is a severe bug if the function object out lives the scope where those references were bound.

Whether the syntax of lambda is beneficial or not, is a matter of preference. I suppose, one could argue that because lambdas make the definition of functors simpler, it also makes the definition of broken functors simpler.

> why does C++11 allow use of a lambda outside the function that declares is or the functions called from it (and therefore introduces the risk of dangling references, etc)?

Firstly, I imagine such semantic limitation would be hard to implement. You can't make them non-copyable because that would make them useless in standard algorithms.

Secondly, because storing a function object for later use is useful, see (2) and using lambdas isn't more dangerous than using instances of named functors, see (1).

> Could you give an example where keeping lambda live outside the declaring function would be desirable?

(2) Just about any asynchronous callback situation. `std::async`, `std::thread`, GUI and other event systems. Callable function objects will be stored for later use in those situations and typically the objects do outlive the scope where they were created.

In general and also in this case, lambdas advantages over named functor types is that you get to place the function definition right where it's used. Well, you can never have the definition where it's actually used in a generic situation of asynchronous callbacks, but the point of registering the callback is as close as you can get.

The disadvantage of lambdas is their hard-for-humans-to-parse syntax that is an explosion of different brackets, braces and parenthesis. Again, this is matter of preference.